# Reducing number of ticks

Tags: plotting

Is there any way to quickly reduce the number of ticks without having to specify them all yourself? There are too many ticks in my plot to show them properly (in a small graph I use to inset into another graph). There is especially no room for accompanying numbers. Say I would like to keep only half the number of ticks (or only show the numbers for half of the ticks), is this possible without having to specify the exact position of all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
   myticksX[min_, max_, n_, tickLen_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   ticks = Table[{i, i, {tickLen, 0}}, {i, 
      FindDivisions[{min, max}, n]}];
   ticks[[2 ;; -2 ;; 2]] = 
    ticks[[2 ;; -2 ;; 2]] /. {a_?NumericQ, 
       b_?NumericQ, {tickLen, 0}} :> {a, "", {tickLen, 0}};
   ticks];
myticksY[min_, max_, n_, tickLen_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   ticks = Table[{i, i, {0.01, 0}}, {i, FindDivisions[{min, max}, n]}];
   ticks[[2 ;; -2 ;; 2]] = 
    ticks[[2 ;; -2 ;; 2]] /. {a_?NumericQ, 
       b_?NumericQ, {tickLen, 0}} :> {a, "", {tickLen, 0}};
   ticks];
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{myticksY[-1, 1, 4, 0.01], 
    None}, {myticksX[0, 10, 5, 0.01], None}}]
```

[image]

**Original Answer:**  How about this?

```
myticksX[min_, max_, n_] := 
     Table[{i, i, {0.01, 0}}, {i, FindDivisions[{min, max}, n]}]
    myticksY[min_, max_, n_] := 
     Table[{i, i, {0.01, 0}}, {i, FindDivisions[{min, max}, n]}]
    Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {myticksX[0, 10, 5], myticksY[-1, 1, 5]}]
```

[image]

Or

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{myticksY[-1, 1, 3], None}, {myticksX[0, 10, 3], 
    None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks (and without undocumented functions the danger of which you pointed out in your comment). Would it be simple to also add smaller unnumbered ticks in between (but keeping the spacing equal between all of them)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` instead of Automatic:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Ticks -> {
    Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity}][##, {3, 3}]&, 
    Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity}][##, {3, 3}]&
    }
]
```

[image]

or:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    Frame->True,
    FrameTicks -> {
        {
        Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity}][##, {3,3}]&, 
        Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity,Identity}][##, {2, 2}]&
        },
        {
        Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity}][##, {2, 2}]&, 
        Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity,Identity}][##, {2, 2}]&
        }
    }           
]
```

[image]

Comment: I am not getting your img with my version 12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)

Comment: @Carl, thanks! Any idea how I can keep the spacing even between ticks though? (Compare the spacing with {3,3} to no Ticks option. The big spacing does not coincide with the small one anymore.)

Comment: @Okkes Does my update produce the same output in M11 and M12 for you (other than the decimal point)?

Comment: @Kvothe Sorry, I don't understand what spacing you're talking about.

Comment: @Carl, sorry I should have been more clear I guess. If you run this without a ticks option you will see that all ticks have equal spacing between them. If we reduce the amount of ticks using your option we see that the "bigger" spacing falls in between the smaller (unnumbered) ones so that the spacing is not equal between that and the others. I would prefer to take out ticks in such a way that this distance is also equal. I think that looks nicer.  (of course that is asking a lot and I am already grateful for being able to reduce the number of ticks in a simple manner).

Comment: @Kvothe I see, you're talking about the fact that the major ticks don't always line up with the minor ticks? For example, the major tick at 2.5 is in-between the minor ticks at 2 and 5, so the distance between the ticks is not always 1. In that case, you could adjust the {major, minor} tick setting to something like {3, 6}.

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes, it works now. Thanks..

Comment: @CarlWoll, should have asked this a long time ago but what is the exact meaning of the numbers {3,3} for example. The first specifies how many large (labeled) ticks there should be and the second the smaller unlabeled ones? Except there seems to be some random element to it (sometimes changing the number does not change anything, then suddenly there are many extra ticks). So I think I probably still don't understand. 

I would love it if there was a reliable way to specify the number of ticks you want or just that you want say half of what Automatic gives you.

Comment: @Kvothe Think of it as a goal, where the criteria is to obtain the specified number of ticks using "nice" values for the ticks, where nice values have finite decimal representations. So you can have 2, 4, 5, 8 or 10 "nice" minor ticks. At least, that's my guess.